# What is Javascript equivalent for this jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and not allowed to use jQuery. I am looking for equivalent plain Javascript code for below jquery:

```
$('img[alt="Apple Store Logo"]').parent().removeAttr("target");
```

I found below information :

```
jQuery         Javascript
parent() :     .parentElement
removeAttr() : removeAttribute()
```

Couldn't find how to construct above selector.

Comment: Please format your code - it makes reading your question much easier. Also, you're likely to get more help if you show an effort.

Comment: jQuery **is** javascript

Comment: @Utkanos : Edited. Sorry for that

Comment: you either use `getElementsByTagName` and loop through all tags to find one that has the matching alt text or you use `querySelector`

Comment: `$(selector) === document.querySelectorAll(selector)`

Comment: @Liam I am aware of that. I am not allowed to use jQuery code and functions. Pure Javascript.

Comment: @scrappedcola `getElementsByTagName()` returns a "live" node list, which may not be right for most situations. `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` are typically the "go-to" methods to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that match the specified selector. Then implement [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over all the elements to remove the attribute from the element's parent node with
[`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Try the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('img[alt="Apple Store Logo"]').forEach(function(el){
  el.parentNode.removeAttribute("target");
});
```

Some older browser does not supprot [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) . Use [`Array.prototype.slice.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) in that situation to implement [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
images.forEach(function(el){
  el.parentNode.removeAttribute("target");
});
```

Comment: The jQuery selector is capable of iterative logic, but `querySelector` only selects the very first element that matches the selector. `querySelectorAll` and then iterating through the returned NodeList is probably the safer way.

Comment: Not all clients support the `Array.prototype.forEach()` method call on a node list. To be sure that you can use it, you should convert the node list to an array: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach();`

Comment: @Mamun: Worked! Thank you Sir!

Comment: @Terry: Thank you! It Worked!

Comment: @ScottMarcus just IE by the looks of it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: @AndrewBone As much as we all would like IE to fall off the face of the planet, it's still used in much of corporate America (and grandmas and granpas).

Comment: @AndrewBone See the note at the beginning of **[this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** on MDN.

Comment: @ScottMarcus IE has a global usage of around 3%, at some point, we have to let it go  If you scroll down on that article it, again, shows IE is the only non-supported browser.

Comment: @AndrewBone It also indicates that it may not be supported on Opera on Android. And, as I said, in corporate America, IE's usage is much higher than 3% (those stats don't take this into account). But, that's really not the point. Why would you write code that you know will fail for 3 out of 100 people that visit your site?

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your call is a simple DOM query retrieving all `<img>` elements with an alt attribute matching "Apple Store Logo".

```
$('img[alt="Apple Store Logo"]')
```

This can be done in vanilla JS easily enough:

```
document.querySelectorAll('img[alt="Apple Store Logo"]')
```

However,`document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not an Array. We can convert the NodeList to an Array by calling `Array.prototype.slice` on it:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[alt="Apple Store Logo"]'))
```

My knowledge of jQuery is poor, but I believe the remaining methods are called iteratively against the elements returned in the query result. Therefore, assuming the intent is to get a reference to the `img` element's parent element, and remove its `target` attribute, the whole code block could be translated to:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[alt="Apple Store Logo"]')).forEach(function (img) {
    img.parentNode.removeAttribute('target');
});
```

Comment: @Tyer. Worked for IE too. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Scott Marcus Thank you!